# Создание label из JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Добрый день!

Необходимо динамически создать набор label внутри form. По какой-то причине код не работает. 
В HTML:

```
   <form>
   <form onsubmit="return MyFunction()" id="AdditionalOption_order">
        <script>  CreateAdditionalOption_new();   </script>
   </form>
```

В JS

```
function CreateAdditionalOption_new(){

    var get_AdditionalOption = sessionStorage.getItem("SParamsUsr");
    get_AdditionalOption = JSON.parse(get_AdditionalOption);
    var list   = document.getElementById('AdditionalOption_order'); 

    for( var key in get_AdditionalOption[3] ) {
        var str_html='';
        var label = document.createElement('label');
        label.for="Note";
        label.class="text-inp-dop";
        str_html=str_html+key;
        label.innerHTML=str_html;
        list.appendChild=(label);
    }

}
```

На выходе новые Label не появляются, данные в sessionStorage.getItem("SParamsUsr") содержатся (проверял через alert). 
В чем ошибка?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
function CreateAdditionalOption_new() {

  var get_AdditionalOption = sessionStorage.getItem("SParamsUsr");
  get_AdditionalOption = JSON.parse(get_AdditionalOption);
  var list = document.getElementById('AdditionalOption_order');

  for (var key in get_AdditionalOption[3]) {
    var str_html = '';
    var label = document.createElement('label');
    label.setAttribute('for', 'Note');
    label.setAttribute('class', 'text-inp-dop');
    str_html = str_html + key;
    label.innerHTML = str_html;
    list.appendChild(label);
  }

}
```

Comment: К сожалению не помогло

Comment: @Дмитрий, вот так попробуйте

Comment: Не увидел разницу относительно Вашего предыдущего варианта, к сожалению не помогло

Comment: @Дмитрий, `list.appendChild=(label);` => `list.appendChild(label);`

Comment: большое спасибо. Теперь все заработало.